# form validate textbox numbers are 0 - 99 and if not alert

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form which asks for a variety of numbers

how many apples then input apples. The id is apple . I have tried onclick and onfocus and not working well. I just want after they go to next box it checks to make sure it is valid number or puts up an alert and focus back on.

Here is what i have for the method.

```
function validate (apple) {
  var textInput = document.getElementById(apple);
  var value = parseInt(textInput.value, 10);
  return ( value >= 0 && value <= 99);
  alert("number wrong")
}
```

here is the code

```
<td><input type = "text" id = "apple" size="1" onkeypress="validate();"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: "and not working well". What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Ummm... isn't "value" a reserved word in JavaScript?

Comment: @Diodeus Not a reserved word, but commonly used as a property of DOM element objects. You can create a variable `var value`.

Comment: Try to use `onchange` for `apple`. Have you noticed that `alert()` does nothing in the function.

Comment: Well the apple field i put in 200 and go to next one i do not get alert it is too high http://hydra.sullivan.edu/mmoore/Assn04/order/order_form.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from the function in all cases before showing the alert. Try:

```
function validate (apple) {
  var textInput = document.getElementById(apple);
  var value = parseInt(textInput.value, 10);
  // Store the comparison's return value
  var ret = ( value >= 0 && value <= 99);
  // Then show the alert if necessary
  if (!ret) {
    alert("number wrong");
  }
  // Finally, return the comparison's result
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: any other ideas as it is not checking the box.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onblur`, which is the event when the element losts focus.

And you did `return` before `alert`, `alert` won't be executed.

Comment: I posted live link above and still unable to get it sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sales_tax_validate (id) {

  var textInput = $("#sales_tax_"+id).val();

  var value = parseInt(textInput);

  var ret = ( value >= 0 && value <= 99);
  // Then show the alert if necessary
  if (!ret) {
    alert("Please enter number between 0 to 99.");
    $("#sales_tax_"+id).val("");
    $("#sales_tax_"+id).focus();
  }
  // Finally, return the comparison's result
  return ret;
}

<input type="text" required name="sales_tax_<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" id="sales_tax_<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $sales_tax;?>" onblur="sales_tax_validate(<?php echo $rows['id'];?>);">
```